# PHP with Oledb

Tags: php, oledb

Can I use PHP with Oledb connection?

As far as I know database connection as provided by PHP extension are all odbc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use ActiveX Data Objects (Microsoft's OLEDB ActiveX layer) in PHP-Win without any third party extension as such:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 

// Microsoft Access connection string.
$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\mydb.mdb");

// SQL statement to build recordset.
$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT myfield FROM mytable");
echo "<p>Below is a list of values in the MYDB.MDB database, MYABLE table, MYFIELD field.</p>";

// Display all the values in the records set
while (!$rs->EOF) { 
    $fv = $rs->Fields("myfield");
    echo "Value: ".$fv->value."<br>\n";
    $rs->MoveNext();
} 
$rs->Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ADOdb Library for PHP](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm) extension.  I've never used it, but it seems to be compatible with OLEDB providers.

Answer (score -1):

maybe......

found an [article](http://www.phpbuilder.com/news/item.php?id=1205) on it.

found the [PHP extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polarscript/files/) for it.

Don't know anything about it. Best of luck.